# STM32F7 trimming step frequency

Tags: stm32, cortex-m4, st

In the past I calibrated the frequency of the High Speed Internal oscillator (HSI) in an STM32F0 device adjusting the value of the register RCC_CR, field HSITRIM. In the ref. manual it says that the calibration step is 40khz, more or less.

Now I'm trying to do the same in an STM32F745, but the ref. manual doesn't say which is the calibration step. At least not in the description of RCC_CR register, and I can't find anywhere where it says this value.

Anybody knows this value?, or better, where is it documented?

Answer (score 3):

This is covered in the [Datasheet](https://www.st.com/resource/en/datasheet/stm32f746ve.pdf)

[image]

Comment: Hi. I had seen that already. However, I still have the doubt because in the case of the STM32F0, this same table also says it's 1%. However, in the description of register RCC_CR, bits HSITRIM it specify that one step is 40khz. Since HSI runs at 8MHz, 40khz is only 0.5%, not 1%

Comment: @naggety 1% is the max. It has to be lower than that. The typical isn't explicitly given, but if it is 0.5%, then everything is consistent.